# facebook login button javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to create a simple FB login that will request email permission...
The ***second block*** is working just fine using ***button option #2***,
But ***second block*** using ***button option #1*** does not call ***authUser()*** function,
& when I try to use the ***first block*** for the same result it does not work either.

1. Why is the **FIRST BLOCK** not calling ***authUser()*** function??
2. Is it because of the login button type?
3. If so, how can I use button option #1 so to enable `data-auto-logout-link="true"`?
4. When using ***button option #2*** in ***SECOND BLOCK*** the ***onClick()*** function is not called either...why?

I can already assume that the facebook button type is causing this and over looking the premissions request in the code...

- both blocks are in the same `<script type="text/javascript">` tag

***FIRST OPTION***

```
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  status     : true, // check login status
  cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});


// Check if the current user is logged in and has authorized the app
FB.getLoginStatus(checkLoginStatus);

// Login in the current user via Facebook and ask for email permission
function authUser() {
  console.log("--- authUser ---");
  FB.login(checkLoginStatus, {scope : 'email'});
}

// Check the result of the user status and display login button if necessary
function checkLoginStatus(response) {
  if(response && response.status == 'connected') {
    console.log('User is authorized');

  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    console.log('User is not_authorized ... ');

  } else {
    console.log('User is not authorized');
    document.getElementById('loginButton').style.display = 'inline-block';
  }
}
```

- Button:

  `<div class="fb-login-button" id="loginButton" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" onclick="authUser();"></div>`

***SECOND OPTION***

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('fb-login').onclick = function() {
  var cb = function(response) {
    console.log('FB.login callback', response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      console.log('User logged in');
    } else {
      console.log('User is logged out');
    }
  };
  FB.login(cb, { scope: 'email' });
};
}
```

- With 2 options for buttons:

  1. `<fb:login-button id="fb-login" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></fb:login-button>`
  2. `<button id="fb-login">FaceBook Login</button>`

     - not using the same button ids in real code, this is just for example

Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried, but it might be helpful.

[Facebook for Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/products/login/)

The special part for JavaScript:

[Facebook for Developers - JavaScript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/)

Comment: Was there, thanx...did find a workaround but aint satisfied...I do suspect it is the way the FB button is called though...

Answer (score 1):

you can find some solution here

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxx";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


   function loginfb() {
    FB.init({
    appId:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    cookie:true,
    status:true,
    xfbml:false
    });
        FB.login(function(responses) {
            if(responses.authResponse)
            {
                FB.api('/me?fields=email,name', function(response) {
alert(response.email);
                });
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```